# Android Live Feed to Website

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I had a quick question and I was hoping you could answer it. So I wanted to design an app that allows me to use my android camera and take that video feed and stream it live on my website, a security cam of sorts. Any idea where to start. I am a complete newbie to android so please dont get too technical. Also, I saw this https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye but was wondering how to modify it for my purposes(Just change the website address to mine I'm thinking). ANy help would be great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you will need to setup an client server socket connection with your android being the server.  Your web server will need a server side program (servlet or similar) to connect to the client requesting a socket connection.  If can then read the stream of data and then make this available to stream to the web client.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, any idea about how to go about doing this, I'm relatively new to all of this.